# Avoid multiple left joins in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following database structure:

```
Users
----------------------
| User_ID | Username |
|--------------------|
|  14590  | Sam      |
|  14591  | Michael  |
|  14592  | Albert   |
----------------------

Addresses
----------------------------------------------
| Adr_ID | City      | Street                |
|--------------------------------------------|
|   62   | New York  | Perfect Street 1      | 
|   63   | New York  | Another Street 12     |
|   64   | Prague    | Zlata Ulicka 52       |
|   65   | Berlin    | Alexanderplatz 36     |
|   66   | Berlin    | Am Bahnhof 49         |
|   67   | Warsaw    | Poniatowskiego 74     |
|   68   | Paris     | Rue Des Barres 33     |
|   69   | Paris     | Rue De L’abreuvoir 63 |
|   70   | Lisbon    | Rua Augusta           |
----------------------------------------------

Addresses_Link
------------------------------------------------------------
| Link_ID | Adr_ID | User_ID | Main_Address | Address_Type |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   570   |   62   |  14590  |       1      |       1      |
|   571   |   63   |  14590  |       1      |       2      |
|   572   |   64   |  14590  |       0      |       3      |
|   573   |   65   |  14591  |       1      |       1      |
|   574   |   66   |  14591  |       1      |       2      |
|   575   |   67   |  14591  |       0      |       3      |
|   576   |   68   |  14592  |       1      |       1      |
|   577   |   69   |  14592  |       1      |       2      |
|   578   |   70   |  14592  |       0      |       3      |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result I want to get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User_ID | Username | Adr_Private_City | Adr_Private_Street | Adr_Job_City | Adr_Job_Street        |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 14590   | Sam      | New York         | Perfect Street 1   | New York     | Another Street 12     |
| 14591   | Michael  | Berlin           | Alexanderplatz 36  | Berlin       | Am Bahnhof 49         |
| 14592   | Albert   | Paris            | Rue Des Barres 33  | Paris        | Rue De L’abreuvoir 63 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Columns:

**Adr_Private_City / Adr_Private_Street** - when Main_Address = 1 and Address_Type = 1

**Adr_Job_City / Adr_Job_Street** - when Main_Address = 1 and Address_Type = 2

I created an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
u.User_ID,
u.Username,
a1.City AS Adr_Private_City,
a1.Street AS Adr_Private_Street,
a2.City AS Adr_Job_City,
a2.Street AS Adr_Job_Street

FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Addresses_Link al1 ON al1.User_ID = u.User_ID
LEFT JOIN Addresses_Link al2 ON al2.User_ID = u.User_ID
LEFT JOIN Addresses a1 ON a1.Adr_ID = al1.Adr_ID
LEFT JOIN Addresses a2 ON a2.Adr_ID = al2.Adr_ID

WHERE 
al1.Main_Address = 1 AND al1.Address_Type = 1 AND 
al2.Main_Address = 1 AND al2.Address_Type = 2
```

Is it possible to avoid multiple left joins and make the query not too slow?

Comment: You have `al1.Main_Address = 1` in the `WHERE` clause, so effectively turning `LEFT JOIN Addresses_Link al1` into a `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with below

Your original query

```
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Addresses_Link al1 ON al1.User_ID = u.User_ID
....
WHERE al1.Main_Address = 1
```

effectively is an `INNER JOIN`, when you have the condition `al1.Main_Address = 1` in the `WHERE` clause

Since you used `LEFT JOIN`, I have turn it into a true `LEFT JOIN` query. For `Addresses_Link` and `Addresses`, since you join it on `Adr_ID`, I use `INNER JOIN`

---

```
SELECT *
FROM   Users u
       LEFT JOIN
       (
         SELECT al.User_ID,
                MAX(CASE WHEN al.Address_Type = 1 THEN a.City END) AS Adr_Private_City,
                MAX(CASE WHEN al.Address_Type = 1 THEN a.Street END) AS Adr_Private_Street,
                MAX(CASE WHEN al.Address_Type = 2 THEN a.City END) AS Adr_Job_City,
                MAX(CASE WHEN al.Address_Type = 2 THEN a.Street END) AS Adr_Job_Street,
         FROM   Addresses_Link al
                INNER JOIN Addresses a ON a.Adr_ID = al.Adr_ID
         WHERE  al.Main_Address  = 1
         AND    al.Address_Type  IN (1, 2)
         GROUP BY al.User_ID
       ) a    ON a.User_ID  = u.User_ID
```